# printing data columnwise in same workbook - java poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Java and POI to print some data to excel files. I think I am just missing a small logic to solve this question. I have data stored in array lists in following format:

```
a = [1,2,3] // arraylist
b = [4,5,6] // arraylist
c = [7,8,9] // arraylist
```

I want to print this data columnwise to excel file in below given format:

```
1 | 4 | 7
2 | 5 | 8
3 | 6 | 9
```

The code that I am using is as below:

```
public final_out = new FileOutputStream(new File(final_output_path));

public XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

public XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("data_vertical_final");

public Row row;

for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {

     String value = a.get(i);
     row = sheet.createRow(i);
     Cell cell = row.createCell(13);
     cell.setCellValue(value);

}

for (int i=0; i < b.size(); i++) {

     String value = b.get(i);
     row = sheet.createRow(i);
     Cell cell = row.createCell(15);
     cell.setCellValue(value);

}

for (int i=0; i < c.size(); i++) {

     String value = a.get(i);
     row = sheet.createRow(i);
     Cell cell = row.createCell(17);
     cell.setCellValue(value);

}

workbook.write(final_out);
workbook.close();
final_out.close();
```

**Error I am getting:**

There is no error, but everything is getting overwritten in new excel file and the final output looks broken. Do I need to make new workbooks for every loop? or there is something I am missing.

**P.S:**

The data that is shown below is just an example. Some of my original files that I am using are between 1000 to 2000 values or maybe more.

I want to dynamically create the rows and extract the values from arraylists and store it in rows that I created.

Comment: Pay special attention to the `i` variable in `sheet.createRow(i);`.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz yea. so it is incrementing in loop making new rows to create cell. is there an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create only `a.size()` rows,
not `a.size() squared` rows.
Don't overwrite them in your code.

I assume that `a.size() == b.size()` and `b.size() == c.size()`.

```
public List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>(a.size());

for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    rows.add(sheet.createRow(i));
}

for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
     String value = a.get(i);
     Cell cell = rows.get(i).createCell(13);
     cell.setCellValue(value);
}

for (int i=0; i < b.size(); i++) {
     String value = b.get(i);
     Cell cell = rows.get(i).createCell(15);
     cell.setCellValue(value);
}

for (int i=0; i < c.size(); i++) {
     String value = a.get(i);
     Cell cell = rows.get(i).createCell(17);
     cell.setCellValue(value);
}
```

If you already solve the problem:
It would be even cleaner to place `a`, `b` and `c` into one collection and use only one loop to iterate through them (in place of 3 separate loops).

I assume that `a` is the longest list.
Check this out:

```
public List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>(a.size());
for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    rows.add(sheet.createRow(i));
}
List<List<String>> alphabet = new ArrayList<>();
alphabet.add(a);
alphabet.add(b);
alphabet.add(c);
for(int i=0; i < alphabet.size(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < alphabet.get(i).size(); j++) {
        String value = alphabet.get(i).get(j);
        Cell cell = rows.get(j).createCell(13 + i*2); //<- 13, 15, 17...
        cell.setCellValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to put this in P.S. but the sizes of lists maybe same and instead of 3, some of my original documents have upto 2000 numbers of value that i need to print into excel. So that way can this method work?

Comment: No. Do not use arrays, if the number of rows is not known.

Comment: i am using arraylist and not arrays. I mentioned it above

Comment: Quite possible ;) But my implementation was not so flexible. Now I switched to `ArrayList`.

Comment: :) okay, just give me a moment. I will try implementing this and be right back in few minutes. Thank you.

Comment: Also, i want to add that here `a` and `b` can be same size but `c` or `d` or etc size can be less than or same as a and b, but not greater than them.

Comment: If `c.size() < a.size()`, there is no problem (some cells will not be filled ;). But if `a.size() < c.size()`, then you will get an exception.

Comment: got it. Its never going to happen :) I l be right back.

Comment: :) works like charm. thank you. This is something new to learn. I never knew we can add rows by putting them in list. good approach.

Comment: also regarding putting a,b and c in one loop. Yes I am looking forward to it. Once I get some of my leftover tasks done, I l improve my code too.

Comment: What is the exact type of `a`, `b` and `c`? How do you declare it? As soon as I have time, I will add it.

Comment: They all are String arraylists. They include numbers, words and some boolean values, all in String form.